# Login failled for user sa

Tags: visual-studio, ssms

Se me esta presentando el siguiente error al momento de conectar a una base de datos SQL con visual studio ya que al parecer al momento de establecer la conexión con el servidor, visual studio no reconoce el usuario con el cual me conecto al servidor sql .

Obviamente al momento de tratar de correr algún proyecto va a generar un error en algún punto de la compilación lo cual ya me ha pasado. Acá les dejo un pantallazo del error agradezco la ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas son las preguntas que me haría yo mismo ¿Lo has intentado con otro cliente como puede ser Managment Studio? ¿Está en una máquina remota y has comprobado la conexión? ¿Has comprobado si el servicio está iniciado?

Comment: el problema es que en visual studio hace la conexion pero al momento de verificar en el explorador de servidores la conexion puedo ver que efecto se establece la misma con la tabla que voy a utilizar para el proyecto lo extraño es que no me deja ver las tablas  porue al hacer click en la carpeta Tables es donde se muestra el error de conexion con el usuario sa que es con el me conecto en sql y no me da problemas

Comment: Obviamente hay algo que no tiene sentido, supongo que ya lo habrás probado, pero elimina la conexión al servidor de SqlServer de Visual Studio y vuelvela a crear, si sigues teniendo problemas conéctate a la base de datos con Managment Studio para comprobar que realmente cuando inicias sesión con 'sa' no te da ningún tipo de aviso cuando te autentiques, y también comprueba que desde este cliente puedes ver las tablas que en VS no. Hay forma de comprobar el log de errores de SqlServer para que te de más pistas. Cuéntanos y vemos si podemos solucionarlo.